Is LR(2) parser more powerful than LR(1) parser?
I understand the working of an LR(1) parser. I came across this post, about LR(2) parser and its differences from LR(1).
Is LR(2) or, in general, LR(k), more powerful than LR(1) parser? Can LR(2) parser parse some grammar that LR(1) can not?
